# node.js hangs other programs on my mac

Tags: node.js

I'm relatively new to Node and javascript. I'm running a program that does heavy network api calls and process the results. What I'm experiencing is that my node code is making other programs running on my mac (Outlook, Chrome, etc.) unresponsive to the point I can't even force quit those programs and have to hard reboot my machine.

Any idea why that's happening? I thought node.js is somewhat sandboxed and shouldn't affect other programs. Is it node using up all sockets available?

Answer (score 0):

seems I've found the reason for node.js itself to use a lot of CPU and memory. I have some code processing thousands rows of user location and calculating the distances. That seems to be very expensive and have a big toll on node. I've moved that code into process.nextTick() and it's not hanging other programs any more.

What I still don't understand is that why node hangs, why it hangs up other programs on my mac as well.

Comment: If you have a process that takes up all the CPU/memory on your computer, you can expect other processes to be affected by that. Mac OS X doesn't necessarily sandbox processes in terms of RAM/CPU usage, although you do have the option (though the `ulimit` shell command) to set some limits.

Comment: thanks for the comment. but my mac has i7 processor which has 4 cores I think? node event loop is just one single thread. I'm not sure how many other threads node uses. so I'm surprised it uses all 4 cores.

Comment: I would think that the memory hogging would pose the biggest problem then. At some point physical RAM has run out and your Mac starts swapping, making it slow.